# How to run multi-line curl statement from a script in terminal?

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, script, zsh

I am attempting to run a curl statement that I copied from Chrome DevTools.  The statement has a bunch of Header parameters.

If I paste this into a Terminal window, it works great.

If I drop this into a shell script, and run the script, each line is executed as its own statement, ignoring the backslash.

```
curl 'https://localhost' \
  -H 'authority: localhost' \
  -H 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'referer: https://localhost' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="107", "Chromium";v="107", "Not=A?Brand";v="24"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  --compressed
```

Do I need to prepend the script with something or invoke it a particular way? I don't do much shell scripting but I'm sure this is an easy one for someone to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say if the outcome in my question has multiple causes, but in my case, the issue was due to CRLF characters in my script:
[image: Script with CRLF line endings - Incorrect]

But they should be LF characters:
[image: Script with LF line endings - Correct]

I was using a Notepad++ editor running on a Windows VM and unbeknownst to me, copy/paste operations reintroduce the CRLF characters!  And I often use a scratch editor tab to do various operations before dropping text into my actual script.

To avoid this issue:

- Use a text editor on the host machine.
- Show End-Of-Line (EOL)
  characters.  *Many editors, including Notepad++, have tools to switch
  between the EOL modes.  But you need to know what is currently
  present!*

Notepad++ Specific Suggestions:

1. Change the default line endings to LF, by going to Settings -> Preferences -> New Document and change the `Format(Line ending)` to `Unix (LF)`:
   [image]

Comment: You can configure Notepad++ to consistently use LF for the line endings (highly recommended - CRLF endings are rarely needed nowadays). The editor shows in the status line, what kind of file has been loaded, so even if you accidentally load a file into the editor which has CR, you can see it and have the editor convert it.